# Create SP 2013 site collection and specify SP2010 site collection data in a content database

Tags: migration

Migrating a SP2010 site collection (http:///sites/root_siteA) to a SP2013 farm
The SP2010 content database (WSS_Content_A) contains data for this site collection only

Restored the content database on SP2013 farm's SQL Server with name (WSS_Content_B) 
Attached WSS_Content_B to specific SP2013 farm's web application

Created a new SP2013 site collection (http:///sites/root_siteB) in the web application (pointed out WSS_Content_B as the content database)

The site collection is empty

Is this scenario of site collection migration supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a site collection on sp2013 with /sites/root_siteB and in the backup of the contnt_b database is a sitecollection with url /sites/root_siteB then the site collection is not restored.

Do not create the SiteCollection Root_SiteB, instead mount the content_b database. This also explains why the SiteCollection B is empty.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a new site collection on SP2013 with the site collection url that is stored in the content database (/sites/root_siteA) in order to get it working?

Comment: No! Dont create a sitecollection on SP2013. Just mount the old database. The Site collection appears after the mounting if it existed on SP2010.

Comment: Thank you, Max. So, what I tried to do is not feasible.There is the only option- mount content db. And actually I just happy with this option.